# Is there a Java equivalent to Unity's Input.GetKeyDown

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, input

Input.GetKeyDown only returns true the frame that the key is pressed. So if you hold the key down it still will only happen once.

[More Info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

Is there a java equivalent?

Comment: Here is a good example to implement that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852914/set-index-of-tabbedpane-when-click-keys/43852956#43852956

Comment: Wait....When you say Java you mean Unity's Javascript/Unityscript or a Java question?

Comment: I mean Java not Unity's JS.

Comment: The answer is **no**. The input API uses events to function. You register to an event input then wait for a callback.

Comment: Ok thank you Ill try and do it some other way

Comment: Unity provides the shortcut for inputs to make things easy on developers. Unity, as an engine, knows that developers are going to want certain behaviors and provides reasonable built-ins. Java on the other hand is a *language* and does not offer those convenient built-ins, you'll have to program it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can switch to JS on the top right corner of the Unity Documentation.
I found that it's literally just

```
Input.GetKeyDown("space")
```

Comment: Im using Java not JavaScript

Comment: Are you asking a question about scripting in Unity or just Java? Don't tag the question with Unity if you don't need help with Unity related topics

Comment: @byIcee to be fair, Java doesn't have anything to do with Unity but I can see where confusion might arise